# Mobile Push failed outbound message

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

I have a list of few contacts (registered OK after the application installation). I am able to deliver "Inbox" messages OK using a list or a Data Extension (with the same data) containing mentioned Contacts.

I am not able to deliver "Outbound" type of a messages though... The send details indicate that there was "No sendable audience".

Could the problem be that all the related contacts have their "Mobile Push Opt-in status" set to "Opted-out"?

Is it possible to hard-code "Mobile opt-out" into the SDK (device/Contact registration)

[image]

Comment: Guaranteed that is a problem.  How are you registering contacts for MobilePush?  What platforms (Android, iOS, both)?

Comment: I can see now that the problem affects only IOS devices... Android users have a proper "Opt-in" (2) status

Comment: 99.999% of the time this is simply a certificate issue.  Please verify that you've uploaded the correct certificate to the Marketing Cloud Servers.  If you need further assistance please open a support case through your support representative.

Comment: It was a cert issue @BillMote - Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99.999% of the time this is simply a certificate issue. Please verify that you've uploaded the correct certificate to the Marketing Cloud Servers. If you need further assistance please open a support case through your support representative.